# Rails timing out too many records to receive or access at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, find

I am currently working on an issue where a report is receiving too much information and causing the subsequent load to either timeout or take a very long time to load all the necessary data. The current function is currently using the find method as I understand it find_by_batches may be better for this but I am unsure how this is implemented my current find is operating on an array key. My intention is still to obtain the data but to possibly batch it so it loads quicker. Below is the snippet and example of the nested array. The issue happens in the nested consumer hash that has many individual consumer records with correspondent key/values.

```rb
module Reports
  class GroupsController < ::ApplicationController

    def consumers
      @group = Group.find(consumer_params[:group_id])
    end

    private

    def consumer_params
      params.permit(:group_id)
    end
  end
end
```

```
Group : {
   key1: value
   key2: value
   key3: value 
   key4: value
   key5: value
}, 
 consumers: {
     {
       key:value
       key:value
       key:value
     },      
     {
       key:value
       key:value
       key:value
     }, etc...
   }
}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe the `Group.find(consumer_params[:group_id])` call is your root problem? What is `consumer_params[:group_id]`? Why would a single `.find` call be the root of your problem?

Comment: Thats a fair point I was under the assumption that the find is the issue because the data set it returns can have up to 9000 records. Because of this, it causes it to take a very long time to load or it times out.

Comment: Again, what is `consumer_params[:group_id]`? If it is an integer, then `.find` should return a single record. Perhaps it's not an integer? Perhaps it's an array?

Comment: It doesnt return an integer. Group_id returns the group with 5 keys and 1 nested array that has all the consumers in it. I will add an example.

Comment: I doubt that's what is returned. You should be getting back an `ActiveRecord` object. And, I suspect those `keys` are actually `ActiveRecord` object attributes. And, the `consumers` "array" (which may well be something other than an `array`) is malformed. In your console, when the `.find` method is called, what does it say about query time? Are you iterating those `consumers` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: That is where i am unsure when I am trying to view the terminal to see what the query is doing its not showing me what ActiveRecord has all I see is the Get request with 
 "GET /reports/groups/1/consumers" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220585/discussion-between-steveks17-and-jvillian).

Comment: It seems as you may have an N+1 problem, would help to see what you're doing with the @group

Comment: I've added my entire control beyond being a variable here in the controller its only used in the views as json such as json.group @group. partial: 'group", as: :group and the same for consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jvillian was correct initially my find was not the issue as the query does not cause any loading issues. After testing different loops all timing was similar. The issue is in relation to displaying such a large data set.

Pagination solved this issue utilizing Kaminari and API-Pagination gems. Utilizing the following code allowed me to break the list into pages of 500 consumers per page.

```
module Reports
  class GroupsController < ::ApplicationController

    def consumers
      @group = Group.find(consumer_params[:group_id])
      @consumers = @group.consumers
      paginate_json: @consumers, per_page: 500
    end

    private

    def consumer_params
      params.permit(:group_id)
    end
  end
end
```

```
json.conference @group, partial: 'group', as: :group
json.attendees @consumers, partial: 'consumer', as: :consumer
```